# Error with pg_upgrade and PostGIS

Tags: postgresql-9.6, postgis

I have a PostgreSQL 9.2 setup (with Postgis) and am trying to upgrade it to 9.6.

When performing the pg_upgrade, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not find function "geography_analyze" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib/postgis-2.0"
STATEMENT:  CREATE FUNCTION "public"."geography_analyze"("internal") RETURNS boolean
        LANGUAGE "c" STRICT
        AS '$libdir/postgis-2.0', 'geography_analyze';

    -- For binary upgrade, handle extension membership the hard way
    ALTER EXTENSION "postgis" ADD FUNCTION "public"."geography_analyze"("internal");
```

I've tried to upgrade `Postgis` on my 9.2 clusters, but I get an error as well:

```
postgres=# ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
ERROR:  cannot drop function "geometry_gist_sel_2d"("internal","oid","internal",integer) because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  operator &&("geometry","geometry") depends on function "geometry_gist_sel_2d"("internal","oid","internal",integer)
operator class "gist_geometry_ops_2d" for access method gist depends on operator &&("geometry","geometry")
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I proceed?

I would try to load the newer version of PostGIS fresh on a 9.6 before you load your dataset. If successful, I would edit the dataset to remove anything to do with PostGIS's internal functions. I would then load my dataset without those offending functions (make sure whatever you're loading does not have PostGIS internal stuff).

Also worth mentioning PostGIS 2.0 is EOL already and unsupported.